# Chrome apps <webview> tag can't change background-color

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to make a google app extension that loads a external webpage having the app frameless. At launch of the program it takes few seconds for the page to load and the  it's all white.
Whatever I do I can't change the background color.

Bellow is a part of the code
Any ideas?

[image]

**manifest.json**

```
   {
        "name": "Stats ",
        "description": "My Stats",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "version": "1.0",
        "icons": {
            "128": "128.png"
        },
        "app": {
            "background": {
                "scripts": ["main.js"]
            }
        },
        "permissions": [
            "webview"
        ]
    }
```

**main.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create("index.html",
    {  frame: "none",
       id: "framelessWinID",
       innerBounds: {
         width: 360,
         height: 300,
         left: 600,
         minWidth: 220,
         minHeight: 220
      }
    }
  );
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stats</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script>
var wv = document.querySelector('webview');
wv.addEventListener('loadcommit', function() {
  wv.insertCSS({
    code: 'body { background: red !important; }',
    runAt: 'document_start'
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="top-box" ></div>

<webview src="" style="width:500px; height:500px;" ></webview>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue here is that Google Chrome apps have a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy) that blocks inline javascript, so you will need to move your script out to its own file.

The second issue is that the [insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-insertCSS) function inserts the CSS into the page that is loaded in the webview, not the webview itself.

I'm not sure if it's possible to set a background style on the webview itself. If your goal is to not have a white box in your app while the page is loading, another approach might be to have a "please wait while the page loads" div overlaying the webview that you show/hide when the page is loading.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stats</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="top-box" ></div>

<webview src="..." style="width:500px; height:500px;" ></webview>
<div id="loading" style="background: red; position:fixed; z-index:999; left:0%; top:0%; width:100%; height:100%;">
    Loading...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
onload = function() {

var wv = document.querySelector('webview');
var loading = document.querySelector('#loading');

wv.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
    loading.style.display="block";
});

wv.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    loading.style.display="none";
});

};
```

Comment: Maybe [`allowtransparency="on"`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#allowtransparency) can help.